# Is it wrong to make words by adding “-ful” to an existing noun?

Tags: word-choice, nouns, adjectives

There arises many cases when we want to use the words like “helpful”, “deceitful” etc. So, I was thinking if I could make up a word by adding “-ful” as a suffix to it, that is convert a noun to adjective by adding “-ful” at the end? For example, if someone says something good and I replied like this :

“Those are very knowledge-ful words”

Is my formation of “knowledge-ful” from “knowledge” correct?

Comment: The full OED attests [***knowledgeful***](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/276478?redirectedFrom=knowledgeful#eid) from 1574, so you'd be following a long tradition if you used it. For the more general case, I'd say ***-ful*** is still a "productive" suffix today for actual ***new*** coinages.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you, is it wrong to write it as “knowledge-ful” instead of “knowledgeably” ?

Comment: The OED [are pleased to offer annual individual OED subscriptions at a reduced rate of £90 (usually £215) or $90 (**usually $295**) until March 31 2021.](https://public.oed.com/about/#) OR if you may be able to get it free through membership of UK public libraries or educational establishments.

Comment: @FumbleFingers is it wrong to write “knowledge-ful”?

Comment: @Knight: I think you'd only be "justified" in hyphenating the ***-ful*** suffix in contexts where you want to give a clear indication that your "neologism" is in fact a one-off "nonce word" (in a real language *spoken* context, you might gesture "air quotes" to make the same point). But frankly, if you have to ask whether it's okay to "play" with language like this, you probably shouldn't be doing it at all. You'll inevitably make mistakes, which might reflect badly on you.

Comment: New Words in the Oxford English Dictionary: Knowledgeful: https://www.vocab1.com/new-words-in-the-oxford-english-dictionary-knowledgeful/

Comment: @FumbleFingers I would like to add that 'knowledgeable' did not come to mean 'knowledgeful' until 1829: https://www.etymonline.com/word/knowledgeable#etymonline_v_30144